Implementation of Timer for Small Root Heap
Use a list to store timer information and sort it from small to large based on the timing time in the timer information. Select the first element with the shortest timing time as the timing time for the core timer. In the callback, reorder the list to select a new timing time. That is, each thread only has one core timer, but there are many timer information stored in the list. Then, want the callback to be in the same thread as this core timer。Because the thread where the timer is located is on the same thread as the signal processing function that calls back after expiration, there will be an operation to reset the timer SetTimer in the signal processing function, and each time it will be stuck in timer_create, but other threads are fine and not affected。
bool posixThreadTimerEx::SetTimer(INT_64 nElapse)
{
    if (nElapse <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << "1";
    KillTimer();
    std::cout << "5";

    memset(&m_sigev, 0, sizeof(m_sigev));
    m_sigev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL; // 使用信号通知
    m_sigev.sigev_signo = m_signalNum; // 实时信号方式
    m_sigev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = this;
    std::cout << "6";

    memset(&m_its, 0, sizeof(m_its));
    m_its.it_value.tv_sec = nElapse / 1000;
    m_its.it_value.tv_nsec = (nElapse % 1000) * 1000000;
    m_its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    m_its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    std::cout << "7";

    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &m_sigev, &m_timerID) == -1)
    {
        int err = errno;
        DIR_WARN("timer_create err is %d", err);
        // DSSKEYUI_ERR("timer_create error");
        return false;
    }
    std::cout << "8";

    if (timer_settime(m_timerID, 0, &m_its, NULL) == -1)
    {
        int err = errno;
        DIR_WARN("timer_settime err is %d", err);
        // DSSKEYUI_ERR("timer_settime error");
        return false;
    }
    std::cout << "9";

    m_nElapse = nElapse;
    std::cout << "0" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
bool posixThreadTimerEx::KillTimer()
{
    if (m_nElapse <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    std::cout << "2";
    if (timer_delete(m_timerID) == -1)
    {
        int err = errno;
        DIR_WARN("timer_delete err is %d", err);
        // DSSKEYUI_ERR("Kill Error");
        return false;
    }
    m_timerID = nullptr;
    std::cout << "3";

    m_nElapse = 0;
    std::cout << "4";
    return true;
}

I tried using the posix timer for the core timer, but found that I had to use the signal notification method of the posix timer, and then I had to handle non asynchronous signal safety functions in the signal processing function, so I kept getting inexplicable deadlocks; I look forward to a new timer that can replace this posix timer or help me optimize it so that the callback function after the timer expires is in the same thread as this timer and there will be no inexplicable deadlock
